# woocommerce - on variable products, auto select the lower price variation in stock

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

for the moment I use this code snippet which pre-selects the first available option. I would like to pre-select only the variations in stock, and if possible the one with the lowest price. Thank you for your help.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args','fun_select_default_option',10,1);
function fun_select_default_option( $args)
{

    if(count($args['options']) > 0) //Check the count of available options in dropdown
        $args['selected'] = $args['options'][0];
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: I'm also interested in this, did you manage to get this thing done?